# Why do I repeatedly get these ads when I have reported them and flagged them dozens if not scores of times?

Tags: discussion

Why do I repeatedly get these ads when I have reported them and flagged them dozens if not scores of times: -

[image]

They are totally inappropriate to me. How can I stop these inappropriate ads being displayed when I go on EE? I don't mind appropriate ads like this: -

[image]

Or this: -

[image]

But, to get these appropriate ads I have to spend about 15 minutes cancelling the inappropriate, unwanted and now thoroughly hated edge impulse ads.

Edit - I have ads disabled by the way: -

[image]

So, although I'm not too bothered about appropriate ads, why am I still seeing ads. I will also add that I've reported ads to SE plenty of times in the past and, more recently, I've made several more reports (maybe 20).

Comment: For reference on MSE: [Report this Ad Feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345476/report-this-ad-feature)

Comment: @toolic interesting but of no use. I've reported the ads to SE probably 50 times and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: I was today years old when I learned that SE has Ads - I have an Ad Blocker tho, and my "home" PC (as opposed to my "work" PC) also gets its DNS through a PiHole.

Comment: "Inappropriate" ads are when you see something really inappropriate for any ad, like gory contents, or boobs. It's not for when you deem the ad to be not fully suited to your preferred activity. It is the equivalent of calling the TV hotline to complain about something that went on air. You wouldn't call the TV hotline if you see an ad for a menthol toothpaste when you prefer strawberry toothpaste, would you?

Comment: Ok, then the feedback you talk about here is the feedback channel that is triggered when you click the cross, and it goes to google directly. Not sure what SE can do here. There is another feedback channel for SE, using the "report this ad" link just below. The options here are "Inappropriate" (likely using my definition of inappropriate), "distracting" (some ads were constantly moving which is annoying) and "other". I'm not sure SE can accept or do anything about some "I am not interested in that product" type of reports.

Comment: If some ad would suggest I'd be interested in old PDIP package assembly, I'd find that offensive :) As for how to reliably make ads go away and not just on this site, I'd recommend Firefox with Adblock Plus plugin. You'd be able to actually use sites like Youtube again, without wading through poorly made ads.

Answer (score 1):

Strange.. I don't get ads on EE.SE at all. Neither on desktop browsers (with ad blocking) nor mobile (without ad blocker). So SE should clarify why you get ads at all.

Also I suppose the category of the two ads are too close for a generic "ads marketing person"..The ad provider could class them both as relating to "digital" or "electronics" or even "technology". You don't see ads for hair dyeing or fashionable child pants or furniture... So I guess the ad provider genuinely thinks that both these ads are appropriate and hopefully they will improve their business if they want to continue selling targeted ad campaigns. SE is not the right address for dealing with this IMO.

Comment: Strangely, in the last 5 days, the occurrences of the unwanted adverts have diminished by 10:1 and, when they do occur I can easily stop the ad from repeatedly occurring. I have to say that I have played around with settings a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that they are not coming from SE and instead being injected into your HTML/CSS by a browser plugin or toolbar add-on.

Disable all plugins, addons, toolbars or any other so called 'free' stuff. Clear your browser cache and lastly try a different browser.

If you still get problems then are you perhaps using a 'free' VPN or, worse a Proxy?  They are also known to insert advertising data into your pages.